# Shuffling a list inside an object in Python

Tags: python, oop, random, blackjack

I'm new to python oop and I'm trying to make a blackjack game.   I create object called cards and I would like to shuffle the cards in pack in `__init__` function, but `random.shuffle(self.cards * self.number_of_packs)` doesn't work, is there any way to do it inside `__init__` function, or do I have to do it outside the Cards object?

```
class Cards:
    def __init__(self):
        import random
        self.onTable = []
        self.cards = ["2 ♥", "3 ♥", "4 ♥..."]
        self.number_of_packs = random.randint(2, 5)
        self.inPack = random.shuffle(self.cards * self.number_of_packs)
```

Comment: note that `import`s should normally appear at the top of the file, not inside functions/methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.shuffle` performs the shuffle operation on the list argument - it doesn't return a new list. You need to generate a new list first of all, and then use `shuffle` to shuffle it:

```
new_list = self.number_of_packs * self.cards
random.shuffle(new_list)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is

```
self.inPack = random.sample(self.cards * self.number_of_packs,len(self.cards * self.number_of_packs))
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample).

The `random.shuffle` shuffles the given argument and does not return anything.

Apart of that it is recommendable to make imports at the very beginning of a .py file outside of any scope.
Also from an OOP perspective it seems unusual to have a `class` called `Cards` with a member called `cards` as well. Maybe have a look [here](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) for some basic guidance.